# How to continue reading from a file when strtok returns NULL

Tags: c, file, printing, segmentation-fault, arguments

I've got a text file:

```
hdsf5 sd3 htf2
```

Using pointers a,b,c and strtoking them works fine.. however

Reading in such lines is fine with my code, but what if "sd3" is missing as such:

```
hdsf5 htf2
```

How would I go about continuing to read from the file, even if a pointer would return null in that case.

Would a simple if `(b == NULL)` (where be is a pointer suffice?

Edit: I've got code along the lines of this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE * ptr;
    char str[100];
    char * a, * b, * c;
    //while loop using fgets...
    // strtok each one...

   //convert each one to an integer using (atol())
  //this is where the seg fault/problem occur
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing concepts here: `strtok` works on a `const char *` string.
You get the string by reading a text file, via `fscanf`, `fread`, `fgets` etc.

When `strtok` returns NULL it means that there is no more token in your string, but it does not mean you cannot keep reading the file (i.e. getting new strings to tokenize): the return value of `fscanf` etc will tell you so.

Comment: I've edited the code, i forgot to mention that I'm converting each char to an int after, however, if I have say one line containing all three of those strings, and the next only containing two, this is where the problem occurs.

Comment: Can you also provide the code of the loop with `fgets` and `atol` ?